# Plagiarism - bachelor thesis

Tags: thesis, mathematics, plagiarism, degree, bachelor

I recently turned in my bachelor thesis and just now realised that there is a missing citation in the text. it's kind of a grey area since i'm mentioning earlier formulas that are cited and based on that say that it will conclude in a specific mathematical expression. I'm unsure if this would be considered common knowledge. since it is a general mathematical expression. If not, would it be considered plagiarism?  The transition from the equation im talking about and the expression that im not citing is not 100% clear. What would you do?

**Edit:** I’m not explicitly deriving the expression. In this specific instance i have explained the nature of a specific model, which im citing. I then go on in a later part and say: ”because of the nature of the ”..”model, When we perform the transformation in equation ”a”and ”b”we can show that the expression will be ”x ”. In this case, ”x” is the amount of deegres of freedoms.

Comment: Is it true that you have no possibility to make a correction? Do they really expect perfection at such an early stage?

Comment: @Buffy Allowing corrections to a submitted thesis should surely be forbidden. Submitting an erratum is probably a better route.

Comment: The reason i’m asking is because the mathematical expression that im not citing is the deegres of freedom of a estimator from a model transformation that is studied in the thesis. Because of the nature of the transformation it follows that the amount of deegres of freedom will be a certain amount. Its not disputed and not someones idea. Rather a mathematical conclusion based on the way deegre of freedoms work. But im not sure. Would it still be best to email the person who will grade the thesis and explain the situation? Or Should i call him?

Comment: From my experience with Bachelor theses my impression is that this kind of thing happens all the time. If you are concerned it's probably not wrong to think about doing something about it, but regardless of this I'd not be very worried that this could be a big problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you state and cite formulas, then derive a further formula. Presumably, the derivation isn't new, and you are concerned that you didn't provide a source for the derivation. Given that you consider the further formula to be well-known, it perhaps doesn't matter so much. Nonetheless, to protect yourself, you could email your examiners and explain that you inadvertently forgot to mention that the derivation is not your own, it is a well-known result, perhaps providing a citation.

Comment: This is too weak and sounds like an excuse. Tell them that you omitted a citation. _Definitely_ provide it.  Offer to provide a corrected copy. Apologize for the error. People make mistakes. Part of the genome. But for various reasons you want the copy corrected in any case.

Comment: @Buffy: You wouldn't cite a well-known formula. Of course, if it isn't well known, then it is too weak. Equally, if it follows trivially, it's obvious. Then again, a bachelor thesis typically gets nit-picked more than a research paper in such regard though.

Comment: The answer suggests erring on the side of "no problem". That is the wrong balance in such a situation. Others will judge the work. If they catch it and think it is plagiarism before you provide a correction then you are in trouble. Err, here, on the side of "abundance of caution".

Comment: @Buffy I found the OP's question rather hard to read. Their now-deleted answer, which seemingly adds further details, didn't help either. I'd likely amend my answer if I were able to better understand the question. As it stands, I'm making guesses, which I've highlighted.

Comment: _If they catch it and think it is plagiarism before you provide a correction then you are in trouble_: That's exactly why I advise emailing the examiners.

Comment: I have no issue with that. The issue is with the word "perhaps". There is no "perhaps", there is only "do". (Apologies to Yoda).

Comment: @Buffy There's really no need to cite a well-known equation. Especially as the author of such might not even be known. The OP writes, _I'm unsure if this would be considered common knowledge. since it is a general mathematical expression._ From that, I don't know whether a citation is required. I can only say _perhaps_, I don't know whether there is any need to _do_.

Comment: The reason i’m asking is because the mathematical expression that im not citing is the deegres of freedoms from an estimator that result of a model transformation that is studied in the thesis. Because of the nature of the transformation it follows that the amount of deegres of freedom will be a certain amount. Its not disputed and not someones idea. Rather a mathematical conclusion based on the way deegre of freedoms work. But im not sure.  Would it still be best to email the person who will grade? Or Should i call him?

Comment: @Erik, yes. Offer a correction. Give the citation.

Comment: @Buffy Would i be better off calling the grader and speaking with him directly or send him an email?

Comment: Sorry, I can't say. Both?

Comment: Okay, thanks for your input. Hopefully he will appreciate my honesty and not fail the thesis. I’m feeling like shit to say the very least.